# Shows on click. Won't hide on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a close button made up of

```
  <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-label="Close"></span></p>

   <div id="tag1" class="tag">
        <p class="p1">Dog Info</p>
        <video id="VideoA1" class="VideoA"><source src=""></video>
        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-label="Close"></span></p>
      </div>
```

The css for this is... so it is hidden at the start.

```
 p .glyphicon-remove{
   color: white;
   font-size: 20px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 5px;
   right: 7%;
   display: none;
 }

 p .glyphicon-remove:hover{
   color: yellow;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size: 25px;
  }
```

As you can see, it is hidden. Then in jquery I basically make the div that contains this button expand when clicked. That works just fine. When the div is clicked I also get the clode button "span" to show(). This also works fine. However I cannot get the same close button to dissappear when clicked.

```
$(".row1 .tag").click(function(){
   $(this).siblings().hide();
   $(this).animate({
     width:"90%",
});
 $(".VideoA", this).css('display', 'none');
 $("p .glyphicon-remove", this).show();
});

$("p .glyphicon-remove").click(function(){
   $(this).hide();
});
```

===========================

Possible Solution:

It seems that I can select the CLOSE button by selecting it's class and then telling jquery to hide it's parent (the span?)

```
$(".glyphicon-remove").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: can you include the surrounding html?

Comment: This is just what I was asking right now

Comment: @depperm I added the html, check my edit.

Comment: I don't understand what do you need to remove. Just the **p** and the **span** or the entire **div.tag**?

Comment: Could you bring up a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I think he founds the solution alone, using **.parent().hide()**

Comment: So there is a <p> it only contains an X icon which is my close button. In bootsrap to get the icon, you use the <span> tag. So really, hiding the span or the p will both hide the close button. The only thing I can't do is hide all <p> tags because as you can see I have <p> tags for text as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **[e.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** to prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event, in your case the click on `.tag` div is fired when you click on `close` button so stopPropagation here is required to prevent that :

```
$("p .glyphicon-remove").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by dynamically and why on would be required?

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense. However I don't think it's added dynamically because it's a part of the html but the initial css shows it as display:none.

So I don't think that is my issue.

Comment: I can see that `$(this).siblings().hide();` hide also the `p` container of close button, are you sure that the show() work fine, check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyCFS/2403/).

Comment: On my page the hide works fine. I have several divs just like the one I posted. It hides those but does not hide anything in the div that is clicked.

Comment: Are you sure that the button close is shown after click on `.tag`? since it has always class `glyphicon-remove` and with this class it should always be hidden because there's `display:none` inside it.

Comment: Yes it does show when clicked. The jquery show() must override the display:none

Comment: Ok check my update and try to add `e.stopPropagation();` it's work on fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/cyCFS/2405/).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. I am guessing that clicking on it made the browser think that the div was also being clicked which made it run the first function again causing the close button to be reshown. You can post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes that exactely what happens, check my update, and good luck.